# My ajax loader is giving me problems

Tags: jquery, ajax, loader

Please help me someone. I have implemented this ajax loader gif image and it works, but when I click on the link a second time it just loads without ever disappearing. I should add that the links are set up in way that if once loaded whenever I click the same link again nothing happens (speaking for myself, it's a bit pointless to load over an already fetched file). Here is a snippet from my code:

```
$('.loadtitles').click(function() {
   $("#myDiv").append('<img src="loader.gif" alt="Currently Loading" id="loading" />');
   window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
  var href = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#SearchFrame').css('display','none');
  $('#myDiv').css('display','block');

return false;
});
```

I tried adding something like this:

```
$('#loading').fadeOut(1000, function() {$(this).remove();});
```

But it doesn't accomplish what I need. I've been playing with the code for a while but nothing that I managed to do suits the fix that I am after. Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also, where did you try to add that?

Comment: Well I thought everything above was the ajax part seeing that it wouldn't work without the jquery library.

Comment: I tried adding it below the append statement and a lot of other places. In the actual code. Are you speaking about the actual code and not just the snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using `append`, a new loading img is created every time you click.
I recommend having the image already in place in the html and just have the jQuery show/hide it as required.

Comment: okay thanks for your help. I will look into that. But still is there no way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you help everyone but I fixed it by adding the jqery (stop) on the necessary part of the overall code. But I would still like to see any other way in which someone else would go about this.